# Node.JS JavaScript socket.io emit message in microservices architecture

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to create a notification feature in Node.JS using Socket.io, and Javascript.

The app.js (the entry script) imports the server.js script (which contains the API endpoints).

Socket.io then listens to app.js (`const io = socket(server)`) and notifies index.html if any notification messages are emitted by the server.

The code works fine if I combine app.js and server.js into one script.

The problem is, when I separate the scripts into a microservices architecture like below, the messages aren't showing.

I can't figure out how to emit a socket.io message from server.js when I split the endpoint code into another script like below.

I've tried importing `socket.io-client` into server.js, then using `const socket=io()`, and emitting a message using `socket.emit('notification','Task completed..!')`. But this doesn't work.

Could you please help me spot the problem?

Thanks in advance!

app.js:

```
const app = require('./server'); 
const socket = require("socket.io");

const port = 6000; 

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App started on port ${port} ...!`)
})

const io = socket(server);

module.exports={io};
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const io  = require('socket.io-client');
const socket=io();

// Express configurations
const app = express()

app.get('/start', (req, res) => {

    // Task completed notification
    io.on("connection", (socket)=>{
         socket.emit('notification',`Task completed..!`);
     });

});

// Export app
module.exports = app;
```

index.html:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Notify</title>
</head>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
  var socket = io();

  socket.on('notification', (msg) => {

    // Create notification element
    var nb = ` ${msg} `;
            
    $('#messages').html(nb);
  
  });
  </script>
  <body>
    <span id="messages"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

app.js:

```js
const app = require('./server'); 
const socket = require("socket.io");

const port = 6000; 

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App started on port ${port} ...!`)
})

const io = socket(server);

exports.io=io; // added
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const io  = require('socket.io-client');
const socket=io();

// Express configurations
const app = express()

app.get('/start', (req, res) => {

    // Task completed notification
    require('./app').io.emit('processing',`Task Completed..!`); // updated

});

// Export app
module.exports = app;
```

index.html:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Notify</title>
</head>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
  var socket = io();

  socket.on('notification', (msg) => {

    // Create notification element
    var nb = ` ${msg} `;
            
    $('#messages').html(nb);
  
  });
  </script>
  <body>
    <span id="messages"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```